# QgsExpression using complex sql and python subsitution

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a sql statement i am running in postgres fine and would like to transfer it to a QgsExpression mainly because I have loaded the layer in Qgis.
My sql is:
 `select column a,column b from 
table1  GROUP BY column a,column b ORDER BY column b DESC limit 20`.  I do not know how to do so. Can I use python substitution when creating an expression.

```
expr = QgsExpression( "%s = 99" )% column a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the [QgsExpression](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsExpression.html#details) class allows you to select features from a layer that match a WHERE clause, i.e., the expression is a conditional that returns True or False (or unknown) for each feature. If the expression evaluates to True for a particular feature, that feature is selected in the map.

What I see from your PostGIS SQL expression is that you want a couple of columns from 20 ordered features. There is no WHERE clause. You could run this kind of expressions from the `DBManager->SQL Window` instead, which can give you subtables that you could eventually load into QGIS as new layers.

**Now, answering your real question**, you can use a Python variable to build your expression in this way:

```
colName= "myColumn"
expr = QgsExpression( "\"%s\" = 99" % colName ) 
print expr.expression() # this should print: "myColumn" = 99
```